Событие удерживания клавиши на SFML
Пытаюсь сгенерировать событие удерживания клавиши на SFML, но не могу найти нужный метод.
В данный момент событие отрабатывается но по умолчанию, как если бы вы нажали на любую клавишу буквы на клавиатуре в текстовом окне: после не большой паузы, отрабатывается со скоростью повтора нажатия, а хотелось бы без паузы и не так быстро.
Если есть какой-то вариант буду рад помощи.
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 300), "Draft");
    
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Space)
                std::cout << "PRESS Space!!!\n";
    }

    window.clear();
    window.display();
}

PS
на комментарии не отвечаю.

Достаточно сохранить между итерациями флажок, что клавиша нажата, игнорировать повторные события нажатия, если он стоит, и снимать его, когда приходит событие отпускания клавишы.

покажите в коде пожалуйста

используй sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed - он как раз и проверяет состояние клавиши в каждом кадре. То есть вместо твоего KeyPressed(которое обрабатывает событие), можно проверять удерживается ли клавиша с помощью вышеупомянутого метода.
на всякий случай, если хочешь контролировать частоту вывода сообщений - добавь таймер sf::Clock, потом добавляешь интервал. получится так, что вывод будет не каждую итерацию, а раз в определенное время
Код:
while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // Проверяем, удерживается ли клавиша Space
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space))
        {
            std::cout << "PRESS Space!!!\n";
        }

        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }


Здравствуйте. Благодарю вас за помощь. Сделал, всё так же, без изменений.

Покажите пожалуйста в коде, что вы предложили сделать

@GreenBrown обновил ответ.
если ответ помог - отметьте его галочокй

Благодарю за помощь. Я описал ваш метод внутри while event, скорее всего поэтому не сработала у меня.
Я отметил ваш ответ галочкой, я бы вас попросил убрать -1 с моего вопроса, если конечно это вы отметили его как "не понятным". Спасибо
